# PHP - array_unique not changing output

Tags: php, arrays, array-unique

I have an array $tmp:

```
$a = array(0 => 49, 1 => 49, 2 => 49);
```

after using `array_unique($tmp)` I'm getting this output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 49
    [1] => 49
    [2] => 49
)
```

and I want to get

```
Array
(
    [0] => 49
)
```

What am I doing wrong? Im new in PHP

Comment: Obviously you show us not real code, or values in array are somehow different. Maybe with spaces or some hidden symbols around. Do a `var_dump($tmp);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$input = array(49,49,49);

$result = array_unique($input);

print_r($result);
```

Comment: Drop-in answer; care to "explain"? for future readers to the question.

Answer (score 8):

You don't only need to call that function you need to use the returned value as well. Do

```
$tmp=array_unique($tmp);
```

Just calling that function and not picking up the returned value does no good.

There are some functions that operate on the original variable and hence you dont need to pick up their ret val for example `sort()` but `array_unique()` is not one of them. Always refer to http://www.php.net/functionName to find out